# How to typeset my research publication?

Tags: graphics, formatting

I have the content for a small research publication ready. I have noticed that the formatting of most of the research papers looks the same.

How can I quickly convert my text to a research formatting?

Though I would like to learn the internals of tex, I might not have sufficient time for it currently. I am looking for a quick solution :)

Comment: You tagged your question with `graphics`, but you don't mention them in your actual question. Did you forget to ask about that aspect, or can the tag be removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the journals provide LaTeX templates on their websites. You just need to download it and fill the content at appropriate locations. But you need to know at least some basics of LaTeX to do everything right and quickly.

Other option, assuming you already have the content in LaTeX format (but not in the format of the journal), you can submit as it is. For the review process formatting to journal standards is not necessary. Once accepted, they retype everything anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your field and the kind of research publication, e.g. conference proceeding or journal paper.

For conference papers there is the [IEEE templates](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html) which should be used for all IEEE conferences. However, if you are in a non-technical field, that might not help you.

For journal papers you have to check the guidelines of the journal in question. Maybe they have a template as well. While conferences often will take your finished PDF directly, **journals will typeset the paper themselves** in their own publishing software. They might need your input in a specific format, depending on their workflow. They usually need the images separately as well. For the review draft you normally can/need to send it in a complete different format, e.g. double spaced lines etc. You need to check the guidelines for the specific format for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

What field?  In math, the "professional"-looking articles all seem to use the `amsart` class, which makes a few changes to the styling of sections and also some rather draconian cuts to the whitespace that gives it a pretty distinctive look.  It does give me some problems with underfull pages, though, when I switch to it in a finished document.

Comment: artificial intelligence field.

Comment: @Lazer: In math, `amsart` is the official style of the American Mathematical Society.  Most journals have their own style files, but perhaps you also have one standard organization that might have its own?